# How to add other website URL in Mongo DB and use it in Website code for redirection?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, web

We are creating a site in which we want if a user login he goes to a page where there is button to download pdf. Pdf file for every user is different that's why we want to put URLs of PDFs in database and use it in website code. We are using MONGODB Nodejs , HTML/CSS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you. You should consider reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).